# Changing download actions in Firefox

Tags: linux, firefox

I'm trying to open a PHP file (locally) in Firefox without the "Do this automatically" box popping up every time.

I tried a bunch of different solutions on the web, they all seem pretty dated.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it "open a .php file locally" i.e. by double clicking?

Comment: Yes. Locally as in on my local hardrive.

Comment: See [mimetype(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mimetype), and [mimeopen(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mimeopen). The mime type of the .php file can be determined using `mimetype`. If it is application/x-php then even if `mimeopen -d` is used to change the default application to Firefox, Firefox won't identify/register itself for application/x-php on the system. Also, Firefox won't be able to open it as it doesn't have a builtin php parser like with html or xml. application/x-php has to be served as HTML by a web server after the .php file (script) is processed by a PHP parser on the server.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I do it all the time with windows. And if I recall, at one time this was working fine with Linux (Ubuntu) as well.

Comment: I may be wrong, so please disregard my previous comment. Do you have ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list, if so can you please temporarily delete it and check.